# Excel sorting strange logic

Tags: excel, sorting

Trying to understand the logic Excel uses to sort data. I read this article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322067/how-to-correctly-sort-alphanumeric-data-in-excel but still have doubts. Let say we have the following values: '10.20/43A' and '100.20/43'. Based on this article alphanumeric values should be sorted by characters, from left to right. So I expect this to be sorted like this (ascending): '100.20/43', '10.20/43A' ('1' == '1', '0' == '0', '.' is not equal to '0' and dot comes later than '0').
But Excel sorts it like this:

```
10.20/43A
100.20/43
```

Could someone explain this?

Comment: `.` comes before `0`. `.` has an ASCII value of `46` and `0` is `48`.

Comment: @Enigmativity So there is a mistake in that article?

Comment: No, actually I was wrong. I was assuming it were a normal ASCII sort order. The article appears to be correct.

Comment: @Enigmativity Then why `.` comes before `0`?

Comment: That's a good question. I put some sample data into Excel myself and got conflicting orderings of `.` and `0`. I suspect that Excel is parsing the text into two parts **if the text starts with a number** and then it sorts the number part numerically and then the text part.

Answer (score 0):

The article is misleading.

When text data is sorted special characters are placed before numbers. For example, text values of "/" "1" and "/1" when sorted will be in order "/" "/1" "1".

If the alphanumeric data is not transformed into text data (ie. you have one numeric cell and two text cells) then the order would be as described in the article. In other words "1" "/" "/1".

The numeric value takes priority only when the format of the cell is numeric. When the format of the cell is text there is a different ordering in which the character values are ordered ahead of numbers.

In your example neither values are numeric and so Excel would order according to text values.